# how to switch between two different texts in jquery..?

Tags: jquery

how to switch between two different texts in jquery..like for ex: "hello" and "glad" should be displayed alternatively and continuosly..please someone help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For switching text among each other you have set timer with jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question leaves a *lot* of information to the imagination, but for instance this will swap those two words, once a second, in an element with the `id` `"target"`:

```
var target = $("#target"),
    word = target.text();
setInterval(function() {
    word = word === "hello" ? "glad" : "hello";
    target.text(word);
}, 1000);
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/uqegos/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/uqegos/1/edit)

Or if you want somthing a bit fancier looking, throw in a fade:

```
var target = $("#target"),
    word = target.text();
setInterval(function() {
    word = word === "hello" ? "glad" : "hello";
    target.fadeOut('fast', function() {
        target.text(word).fadeIn('fast');
    });
}, 1000);
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/uqegos/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/uqegos/2/edit)